# Webcam is not working

Tags: windows-7

I am facing a problem with my webcam of my Lenovo thinkpad X201i. It is not working. when I go to webcam option it says "the webcam is not found or not working properly, click connect button". when I click connect button it says "camera not found, the camera is in use by another application or not connected." I checked Device manager and there is no option named Imaging manager or something else. I also tried "Universal serial controllers" but there is nothing as well. 
I need help. 
Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. 
Thank you.
Arif

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you should try installing the original [driver](http://support.lenovo.com/au/en/products/Laptops-and-netbooks/ThinkPad-X-Series-laptops/ThinkPad-X201/downloads/DS001073) for your notebook's webcam.